# Why do my posts keep getting cut off after a few words in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, post, plugins, trim

I've created a static page and by using the "Posts in page" plugins, have added a single post to the page.
but it seems that the post is cut off and adds a [...] at the end of the post.
I've checked the page.php file and it says `<?php the_content(); ?>`
where the content should appear.
How can I show the complete post, without getting it trimmed?

Comment: found it, posts-in-page/posts_loop_template.php file had overrid the page.php "the_content", with "the_excerpt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
 posts-in-page/posts_loop_template.php
```

Change

```
"the_content" to "the_excerpt"
```

LOL, I got them seer skillz.